# opengl lighting is reversed on each model

Tags: java, opengl, glsl

I have a problem where the lighting in my model looks as if it is reversed on every model that is rendered.  I am lighting a field of tiles, each tile encapsulates an 8x8 subset of smaller tiles so each larger tile contains 4*8*8 vertices.

[image: Strange lighting effect...]

I have the normal set to 1 in the Y direction - tried reversing it but of course that made the lighting point the other way so the scene went dark.  Also tried reversing the winding for all triangles but that just produced a completely garbled mess.  I do pass the normals and light position to a shader but I can't see anything there that would produce this effect.  I've poked around the shader changing various signs etc but nothing fixed it.
Has anyone seen this before?  What would I be looking for to fix it?

There is a ton of code involved in this project so I'll just post what I think is relevant.

**Init the arrays for VBO data:**

```
public void initVBOData(int _worldID, int SIZE, ArrayList<Cube> c){
    int i = 0;

    cubes = c;

    worldID = _worldID;
    QUAD_SIZE = SIZE;

    //the vertices for each tile
    vertBuffer[0] = 1;
    vertBuffer[1] = 1;
    vertBuffer[2] = 1;

    vertBuffer[3] = -1;
    vertBuffer[4] = 1;
    vertBuffer[5] = 1;

    vertBuffer[6] = -1;
    vertBuffer[7] = 1;
    vertBuffer[8] = -1;

    vertBuffer[9] = 1;
    vertBuffer[10] = 1;
    vertBuffer[11] = -1;

    for (int x = 0; x < QUAD_SIZE;x+=1 ){
        for (int z = 0; z < QUAD_SIZE;z+=1 ){

            vertBuffer[i + 0] = vertBuffer[0] + (2 * x);
            vertBuffer[i + 1] = vertBuffer[1];
            vertBuffer[i + 2] = vertBuffer[2] + (2 * z);
            vertBuffer[i + 3] = vertBuffer[3] + (2 * x);
            vertBuffer[i + 4] = vertBuffer[4];
            vertBuffer[i + 5] = vertBuffer[5] + (2 * z);
            vertBuffer[i + 6] = vertBuffer[6] + (2 * x);
            vertBuffer[i + 7] = vertBuffer[7];
            vertBuffer[i + 8] = vertBuffer[8] + (2 * z);
            vertBuffer[i + 9] = vertBuffer[9] + (2 * x);
            vertBuffer[i + 10] = vertBuffer[10];
            vertBuffer[i + 11] = vertBuffer[11] + (2 * z);  
            i+=12;
        }
    }

    //the IBO index values
    i = 0;
    idxBuffer[0] = 1;
    idxBuffer[1] = 0;
    idxBuffer[2] = 3;
    idxBuffer[3] = 3;
    idxBuffer[4] = 2;
    idxBuffer[5] = 1;
    for (int x = 1; x < 64; x++){
        i+=6;
        idxBuffer[0 + i] = (4 * x) + 1;
        idxBuffer[1 + i] = (4 * x) + 0;
        idxBuffer[2 + i] = (4 * x) + 3;
        idxBuffer[3 + i] = (4 * x) + 3;
        idxBuffer[4 + i] = (4 * x) + 2;
        idxBuffer[5 + i] = (4 * x) + 1;
    }

    //the normals for each vertex.
    for (i = 0; i<vertBuffer.length;i+=3){
        normals[0 + i] = 0;
        normals[1 + i] = 1;
        normals[2 + i] = 0;
    }

    //the uvs for texture
    for (i = 0; i < UVs.length; i+=32){
        System.arraycopy(yellow, 0, UVs, i, 8);
        System.arraycopy(red, 0, UVs, i + 8, 8);
        System.arraycopy(green, 0, UVs, i + 16, 8);
        System.arraycopy(blue, 0, UVs, i + 24, 8);
    }
}
```

**Light position and direction (set in draw() method):**

```
    glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the framebuffer

    //calc rotate camera
    if (updatecamera == true){
        updateCamera();
    }

    glUseProgram(shader.iProgram);

    Vector4f lp = new Vector4f(lightX, lightY, lightZ,1.0f);

    //camera is the 4x matrix representing 'lookAt'
    shader.setUniform(iLightCam, camera);
    shader.setUniform(iLightVec, lp);
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
#version 430

in vec3 Position;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec2 TexCoord;

//uniform sampler2D Tex1;
layout(binding=0) uniform sampler2D Tex1;

struct LightPos {
    vec4 LightVector;
    mat4 CameraPos;
};
uniform LightPos SetLight;

struct LightInfo {
    vec4 Position; //light pos in eye coords
    vec3 Intensity; //ads light intensity 
};
uniform LightInfo Light;

struct MaterialInfo {
    vec3 Ka; //ambient reflectivity
    vec3 Kd; //diffuse reflectivity
    vec3 Ks; //specular reflectivity
    float Shininess; //specular shininess factor
};
uniform MaterialInfo Material;

layout ( location = 0 ) out vec4 FragColor;

void phongModel (vec3 position, vec3 norm, out vec3 ambanddiff, out vec3 spec)
{

    vec4 LightPosition = SetLight.LightVector * SetLight.CameraPos;

    vec3 s = normalize( vec3(LightPosition) - position);
    vec3 v = normalize( -position.xyz );
    vec3 r = reflect( -s, norm );
    vec3 ambient = Light.Intensity * Material.Ka;
    float sDotN = max( dot( s, norm ), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = Light.Intensity * Material.Kd * sDotN;
    spec = vec3(0.0);

    if ( sDotN > 0.0 ) 
        spec = Light.Intensity * Material.Ks * pow(max( dot(r,v), 0.0), Material.Shininess);

    ambanddiff = ambient + diffuse;
}

void main(void) 
{
    vec3 ambanddiff, spec;
    vec4 texColor = texture( Tex1, TexCoord );

    phongModel (Position, Normal, ambanddiff, spec);
    FragColor = vec4(ambanddiff, 1.0) * texColor + vec4(spec, 1.0); 
}
```

**The vertex shader**

```
#version 430

layout (location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 VertexNormal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 VertexTexCoord;

out vec3 Position;
out vec3 Normal;
out vec2 TexCoord;

out vec4 MVPPos;

uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat3 NormalMatrix;
uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main()
{
    TexCoord = VertexTexCoord;
    Normal = normalize( NormalMatrix * VertexNormal );
    Position = vec3( ModelViewMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition,1.0) );
    //gl_Position = MVP * vec4(VertexPosition,1.0);
    MVPPos = MVP * vec4(VertexPosition,1.0);
    gl_Position = MVPPos;
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly provide your vertex shader code as well?

Comment: Just a thought, but maybe its because you are using the normalized coordinates for your LightPosition in your diffuse calculation, instead of just the normal world coordinates?

Comment: If use this, anything that isn't centered around your origin will probably not be lit up.

Comment: I'd start by drawing normals (as a colour such as `FragColor=vec4(Normal*0.5+0.5,1)`), then focus on `LightVector * CameraPos` (which is constant and should be passed in pre-computed, but also I find the transposed/reverse multiplication quite odd). Then draw `LightPosition`  and `s` to check `position` is correct. At least one of these will be wrong to give incorrect diffuse lighting (leave spec until diffuse works) and the fastest way to check is to draw the vector as colour. also, due to linear interpolation you'll need to re-normalize your normals in the fragment shader.

Comment: I've posted the vertex shader code as well.  These are great debugging suggestions - (not allowed to say thanks...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After three days I finally figured it out.  My only clue was that the lighting was somehow 'reversed' so I spent a lot of time changing signs for - to + and vice versa and changing various orders of multiplication.  In the end the error was not in my shaders.  The value that I was passing to the "ModelViewMatrix" in the vertex shader was being calculated in the wrong order.

```
        Matrix4f.mul(model, camera, modelview); 
        shader.setUniform(iModelView, modelview);
```

Should be:

```
        Matrix4f.mul(camera, model, modelview); 
        shader.setUniform(iModelView, modelview);
```

[image: All good now]